# Qt5: show notification popups

Tags: qt, notifications

I'm writing an image viewer which allows me to do some actions. As a visual feedback to some actions (like copy/move/delete/..) I'd like to have a decent popup in the middle of my application window which informs about what has been done and which disappears after about a second.

Of course I can just use a Widget and and modify it to fit my needs:

- placed in the middle/on top of application window (regardless of layout)
- disappears after a given time
- no interaction/focus possible - clicking on the notification should be like clicking on what's behind of it
- decent style (e.g. transparent and easily readable)

.. I'm just wondering if there's something dedicated for this purpose

(I'm NOT talking about tray notifications which appear near to some task barof the window manager)

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve a nice popup **fade in/fade out** effect using animation effects in qt ,sample code is given below :

```
QGraphicsOpacityEffect* effect=new QGraphicsOpacityEffect();
this->label->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
this->label->setStyleSheet("border: 3px solid gray;border-radius:20px;background-color:#ffffff;color:gray");
this->label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
this->label->setText("Your Notification");
QPropertyAnimation* a=new QPropertyAnimation(effect,"opacity");
a->setDuration(1000);  // in miliseconds
a->setStartValue(0);
a->setEndValue(1);
a->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::InBack);
a->start(QPropertyAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
this->label->show();
connect(this->timer,&QTimer::timeout,this,&Notifier::fadeOut);
this->timer->start(2000); // 1000 ms to make the notification opacity full and 1000 seconds to call the fade out so total of 2000ms.
```

and your fadeout method as:

```
void fadeOut(){
    QGraphicsOpacityEffect *effect = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect();
    this->label->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
    QPropertyAnimation *a = new QPropertyAnimation(effect,"opacity");
    a->setDuration(1000); // it will took 1000ms to face out
    a->setStartValue(1);
    a->setEndValue(0);
    a->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::OutBack);
    a->start(QPropertyAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
    connect(a,SIGNAL(finished()),this->label,SLOT(hide()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sound like you want to use a [`QMessageBox`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html). For instance:

```
QMessageBox* msgbox = new QMessageBox(this);
msgbox->setWindowTitle("Note");
msgbox->setText("Successfully copied item foobar");
msgbox->open();
```

You might want to change the [modality](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#setWindowModality) according to your desire and implement a timer  to close the dialog.

```
QTimer* timer = new QTimer(this);
QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), msgbox, SLOT(close()));
QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), timer, SLOT(stop()));
QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), timer, SLOT(deleteLater()));
timer->start(1000);
```

*Note:* Example code, not tested.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if you are in python or C, but may have a look to this:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmessagebox.html

Nevertheless, I would go for a new window (QWidget) and modify it. Its only a couple of lines, and the automatic close you can do by a Qtimer.